# How to fix unity vuforia camera shake

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Help pls. My model have bad shake.

My image have 5 stars - http://prntscr.com/nttbha

Video - https://youtu.be/cpScvaszcmo

World center mode - First_taret

Vuforia settings - http://prntscr.com/nttc3j